# Node js server not starting

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js. Just started to learn node js. When I am creating own server it is not initializing. Can someone help me in resolving this error.

```
const http * require('http');

const hostname * '127.0.0.1';
const port * 3000;

const server * http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode * 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World!');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('server started on port '*port);
});
```

Error:

```
C:\test\app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { const http * requi
re('http');
                                                                    ^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:605:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:613:3
```

Comment: [SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_initializer_in_const) - see chapter `What went wrong?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `*` to `=`

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World!');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('server started on port ', port);
});
```

Comment: yeah thanks Bless can you explain why it is went wrong when i coded with * mark

Comment: It's because `=` is the syntax for assignment operator in JavaScript. And `*` is multiplication operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just try again with this '=' operator and run the code..

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode * 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
    res.end('Hello World!');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log('server started on port '*port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace * to = it will work

```
  const http = require('http');
  const server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-type','text/plain');
        res.end('Hello World!');
    });
      server.listen(9090, function(error){
      if(error) throw error
      console.log("Server created Successfully")
    })
```